# Django Python - query count for the month and the past 6 months

Tags: python, django, count

I'm using Django `1.10.5` with python `3.6`.

I have the following model class:

```
class PublishedRecordedActivity(models.Model):
    published_details = models.ForeignKey(PublishedDetails, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    activity_type = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
```

I want to count the number of records for an activity type (1, 2, 3 or 4) for the current month and also for each of the past 6 months.

For example, a count for the entire current month (April 2019).

A count for one month ago (the entire month of March 2019).

A count for the two months ago (the entire month of February 2019), etc.

I can write the query for the count, but I am unsure how to add the filter for each entire month.

Here is my query:

```
test_count = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(activity_type=1).count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, find out the month in which you want to filter. For that, use [**`relativedelta`**](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) function from [**dateutil**](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package

```
In [33]: from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                                             

In [34]: from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta                                                                                                                                                          

In [35]: months_before = 6                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [36]: now = datetime.utcnow()                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [37]: now                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[37]: datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 8, 5, 6, 42, 300424)

In [38]: from_datetime = now - relativedelta(months=months_before)                                                                                                                                                 

In [39]: from_datetime                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[39]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 8, 5, 6, 42, 300424)

In [40]: modified_from_datetime = from_datetime.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)                                                                                                          

In [41]: modified_from_datetime                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[41]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

Then use the **`modified_from_datetime`** variable in your filter with [**`gte`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte) ,

```
PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(activity_type=1, timestamp_added__gte=modified_from_datetime)
```

---

### Complete Snippet

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

months_before = 6
now = datetime.utcnow()
from_datetime = now - relativedelta(months=months_before)
modified_from_datetime = from_datetime.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(activity_type=1, timestamp_added__gte=modified_from_datetime)
```

---

### UPDATE-1

Use group-by feature as,

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

aggregated = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(
    activity_type=1).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added')).values('month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('month'))
```

Comment: thanks, but your answer gives me a total count for the past 6 months. I am seeking a count for each separate month in the past 6 months.

Comment: check my `UPDATE-1` section

Comment: Thank you very much! The update-1 you provided solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can get monthly aggregated values by using Django's `annotate` and `TruncMonth` and `Count` database function. Usage example is given below

*i.e*

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

aggregated = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(activity_type=1).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added').values('month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('id'))
```

This would give you monthly aggregated counts of particular activity type. You can add other filter applying time range on `timestamp_added` field.

if you want to aggregate just only for past 6 months than do follow.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
current_date = date.today()
months_ago = 6
six_month_previous_date = current_date - timedelta(days=(months_ago * 365 / 12))

aggregated = PublishedRecordedActivity.objects.filter(activity_type=1, timestamp_added__gte=six_month_previous_date).annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp_added').values('month').annotate(sum_by_month=Count('id'))
```

> Replace `months_ago` with months aggregate you want

This would help you. If further help needed then put comments below

Comment: This would return count by months. i.e   1/2019, count:2  ; 2/2019, count:5; .... 12/2019, count:6 ....

Comment: using your suggestion, how do I apply the filter to the `timestamp_added` for say 4 months ago?

Comment: I have updated my answer have look into it. It returns previous six months aggregation values grouped by each month with specific `activity_type`.

Comment: This would return you each months count separately.